# Coffeescript Classes

Tags: class, oop, object, coffeescript

I have started using Coffeescript recently, and I don't quite have a grasp on classes. I tried using the tutorial on Coffeescript.org and this is what I came out with:

```
class Item
    constructor: (@name, @description) ->

    add: () ->
        $itemsBox.append("<p class='center item #{@name}'>#{@name}</p>")

    remove: () ->
        $itemsBox.remove($("##{@name}"))

class permanentItem extend Item 


    add: () ->
        super()

    remove: () ->
        super()

class permanentUsableItem extend Item
    @used: false
    @active: true

    add: () ->
        super()
        $useItemSelection.append("<option value='#{@name}'>#{@name}</option>")

    remove: () ->
        $("#useItemSelection option[value='#{@name}']").remove()

class usableItem extend Item
    @numberHeld: 0
    @active: false

    add: () ->
        $itemsBox.append("<p class='center item #{@name}'>#{@name} x#{@numberHeld}</p>")
        $useItemSelection.append("<option value='#{@name}'>#{@name}</option>")

    remove: () ->
        if @numberHeld is 0
            super()
            $("#useItemSelection option[value='#{@name}']").remove()
        else 
            @numberHeld -= 1
```

Can anyone tell me if this is correct, will all of the `#{@name}`s work fine, and does super only refer back to the method with the same name in the parent class?

Comment: Looks fine, at first glance. Are you encountering a problem or have a specific question of some sort? If not, unfortunately this question would be considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: Whats the question exactly? Does the above not work how you expect it to?

Comment: I have not compiled it yet, but I am confused about the use of super, and I thought that asking some of those other questions would be appropriate.

Comment: I think you need function binding with `=>` to access `@attributes`

Comment: @thkang Not quite. Since the OP put a `@` in front of them, they become class variables. So `@active` would have to be accessed `UsableItem.active` instead of `@active` or `this.active` (which won't work). To make them instance variables in the same manner, they would simply remove the `@` symbol, and then they would be "safe" to use `@active`. However, that works only if the `this` context is preserved (which it wouldn't be in an event callback, for example), in which case, you're right the `=>` would be required in that situation.

Comment: *Note: That reply was partly for the benefit of the OP, in case they weren't aware of that distinction.*

Comment: @Teeg So will `@active` be different for every instance I make or do I have to get rid of the @ for that to happen?

Comment: @LukeK You'd have to ditch the `@` for that. Note that since you're assigning that field immediately, it will technically always be the same for every instance at first (when the object is constructed), until you change it for that instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the karma to add this as a comment, so I'll add it as an answer instead.  Here are a few things you might want to be aware of:

1. The keyword is `extends`, not just `extend`.
2. Are `$itemsBox` and `$useItemSelection` global variables? I don't see where they are defined otherwise.
3. Any method (except the constructor) for which you use the `@foo` syntax should be declared with the "fat arrow" `=>`.  `@foo` is equivalent to `this.foo`, and the `=>` version is the only one that binds `this` to the right object (the specific instance of your class).
4. I think the convention is to use CamelCaseWithALeadingCapital for class names, so you'd have `class UsableItem` rather than `class usableItem`, but that is just a matter of personal taste.

Other than that I think your code looks like it will work.

Note that if you just want to do a syntax check, or see the JavaScript that is generated for a bit of CoffeeScript, you can go to http://coffeescript.org/ and click on the "Try CoffeeScript" tab.